# Flink 1.11 StreamingFileSink flush record(s) early to in-progress file

Tags: hdfs, apache-flink, flink-streaming

We have a hourly bucketed `StreamingFileSink` (to HDFS) where records are relatively infrequent.
Is there a way to configure Flink to flush records to `in-progress` file as soon as they arrive (less than 1 minute), instead of Flink keeping them in buffer?

The requirement is for successor data analysis process to read `in-progress` file near-real time.

I know how to shorten `InactivityInterval` but it results in too many small files in the end, which is undesirable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can look at the implementation of the write function. There are several implementations which will write the data to the hdfs file in real time.StreamingFileSink itself will not keep them in buffer, but there will be some buffers inside the FileOutputStream

```
public interface InProgressFileWriter<IN, BucketID> extends PartFileInfo<BucketID> {

/**
 * Write a element to the part file.
 *
 * @param element the element to be written.
 * @param currentTime the writing time.
 * @throws IOException Thrown if writing the element fails.
 */
void write(final IN element, final long currentTime) throws IOException;

/**
 * @return The state of the current part file.
 * @throws IOException Thrown if persisting the part file fails.
 */
InProgressFileRecoverable persist() throws IOException;

/**
 * @return The state of the pending part file. {@link Bucket} uses this to commit the pending
 *     file.
 * @throws IOException Thrown if an I/O error occurs.
 */
PendingFileRecoverable closeForCommit() throws IOException;

/** Dispose the part file. */
void dispose();

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

/** A handle can be used to recover in-progress file.. */
interface InProgressFileRecoverable extends PendingFileRecoverable {}

/** The handle can be used to recover pending file. */
interface PendingFileRecoverable {}
```

}

Comment: Thank you. It led me to https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.11.2/flink-core/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/serialization/SimpleStringEncoder.java#L66-L67, I found that the encoder is simply writing to stream, but not explicitly flushing.

Comment: Do you think creating a custom encoder with explicit stream.flush() in its encode function (and use it only for the low throughput sink) is a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

StreamingFileSink time data is written to HDFS in real time and will not keep them in buffer

In order to support exactly once semantics, the in-progress file will only be renamed into a formal file during checkpoint and then you can do successor data analysis

StreamingFileSink does not support real-time data query, you can reduce the interval of cp to improve the real-time performance of data visibility， but if the cp interval is too small, it will easily lead to small file problems

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Would you mind pointing me to any reference (document and/or code) that "StreamingFileSink time data is written to HDFS in real time and will not keep them in buffer"?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the enable the file compaction option? https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/table/filesystem/#file-compaction

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Let me probably check with PIC of successor data analysis process. So according to the statement "Only files in a single checkpoint are compacted, that is, at least the same number of files as the number of checkpoints is generated.", with my requirement (<1 minute), checkpoint interval can be set to 1 minute, then there will be 60 files per hour?

Comment: And BTW is the feature available with Flink 1.11?

Comment: I believe this capability was added in Flink 1.12 as part of the new File Sink implementation.

Comment: Indeed, if you have 1 file generated every minute and one minute checkpoint interval, Flink will generate 1 output file every minute, so you would end up with 60 files after one hour.